# Contradiction in Java documentation for ExecutorService method shutdown()

Tags: java

Here is the first line in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()):

> Initiates an orderly shutdown in which **previously
>   submitted tasks are executed**, but no new tasks will be accepted.
>   Invocation has no additional effect if already shut down.

And here is the second line right beneath the previous one:

> This method
>   **does not wait for previously submitted tasks to complete execution**.
>   Use awaitTermination to do that.

So which is it? Does `shutdown()` wait for previously submitted tasks to be executed before shutting down or doesn't it?

Comment: It's just saying that it's an asynchronous (i.e. non-blocking) version of `awaitTermination`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth got it. if that were an answer, i'd accept it

Comment: It's not an asynchronous version of awaitTermination. awaitTermination just waits. It doesn't shutdown.

Comment: Where do you see the contradiction? Are you perhaps misunderstanding 'Initiates'? http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/initiate

Answer (score 5):

There is no contradiction. The method just tells the executor "please don't accept new tasks" and returns immediately. The thread which asked for shutdown can then keep doing something else, while the executor keeps executing the submitted tasks, in parallel.

Comment: Compare this with `shutdownNow()`, which indeed will attempt to stop all running tasks immediately and throw away all waiting tasks too. (But even that method call doesn't wait for all that to happen.)